# Example for negative entropy change in an Open thermodynamic System (Practical Scenario)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Can any one cite an example for a practical scenario (preferably not involving chemical reactions) wherein entropy change is negative. Viz. heat flows from a "Thing" to a second 'thing' at equal or higher temperature. Can we use such systems as efficient energy generation mechanism.

Comment: Energy generation as in to create energy?

Comment: [Heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump) It save electricity so it's more energy efficient than simple electrical resistance heaters

Comment: For achieving negative entropy change you need to use external energy for that. So this process not generates energy, but in reverse - extinguishes external energy applied. One of such devices - heat pump, given by @Aleksey.

Answer (score 2):

The most practical example - a freezer. The entropy falls locally while the heat is taken outside the chamber.

Second example - a rubber band. Touch the rubber band to your upper lip and stretch it. You will feel the heat. This is entropy escaping the material in the form of heat. Entangled polymers that the rubber band is made of are getting straighten, thus the entropy falls locally.

Comment: I thank all for citing examples. In all these external work is done to exchange heat from lower to higher temperature medium. But I was wondering if by virtue of pressure or some other parameter whether an incoming matter could transfer its energy to body at higher temperature in aopen thermodynamic system where both matter and heat transfer is involved....

Comment: @Muralidhar M,    maybe you mean [Dissipative structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_system#cite_note-England-7)?  But this is a completely different concept.

Comment: @Muralidhar_M by virtue of chemical potential you are able to do something analogous to what work (pressure) have done in my previous examples. If you connect a very salty water with fresh water in higher temperature with a membrane that blocks water but not salt, salt will go to the fresh water decreasing the entropy in the salty water.

Comment: Thanks for indicating Dissipative structures that is something new I learned! I am wondering if a fluid can exchange its internal energy with a gas at least under non-equilibrium condition, then due to high Specific heat differences can't we think entropy change could be in negative direction..

Comment: This is a great answer @Licho. Would you consider to be a private beta user on Materials? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZjcxNmMxZjA3ZGFkNWJiMjRhZGQxNjAzY2E0ZTAxYzYzOTc2Yjk4YTFiYWVlZDA2YjlmYWI3NTE0OTNmOGI3OBKIibVWqhq0HqTbmyaNJVtUCXoNz7CCexf2SvvYcVjQ0 It's for the design of new materials: solar cells, photovoltaics, bio-materials, superconductors for quantum computing, new materials for better batteries, energy storage materials, molecular magnets, energy conversion materials, stronger and lighter materials for cars, bikes, planes, spaceships, etc.

Comment: @MuralidharM So you are basically asking if the second law of thermodynamics is true for a non-equilibrium system? First of all in a non-equilibrium system, there is no definition of internal energy nor specific heat. Entropy is defined differently. Non-equilibrium systems are prone to fluctuations, so by the virtue of fluctuation it can happen. But if you think you have found perpetuum mobile - don't get excited. You most probably haven't. It's just a random event like 3 heads in the row when flipping a coin.